# laravel 5 : How to return view with response

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two `return` in my controller method.

For view :

```
return view('user.profile',compact('user','tickets'));
```

For response :

```
return response()->json(array('someData1'=>$someData1,'someData2' => $someData2));
```

How can I combine both?

Comment: what you want to achieve ?

Comment: return view for direct access and json for ajax. Right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to return the response depending on the request type.
 If you want to send the compiled view via your json response please see the @Vojo123 's answer
 
To achieve this you can first check if the request is ajax or not and then return the proper response.
In your method use following code.

```
    if($request->ajax()){
         return response()->json(array('someData1'=>$someData1,'someData2' => $someData2));
    }
    return view('user.profile',compact('user','tickets'));
```